# left join to two inner joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure i'm probably just being forgetful or overcomplicating... but here's my scenario:

### Calendar table (record for every day of every year)

```
iso_date
01/01/01
02/01/01
03/01/01
04/01/01
```

### Venues table (record for every venue)

```
venue
All London
London Tower
London Bridge
Millenium Bridge
```

### Composite venues table (reference to linked venues)

```
master_venue,     child_venue
All London,       All London
All London,       London Tower
All London,       London Bridge
All London,       Millenium Bridge
London Tower,     London Tower
London Bridge,    London Bridge
Millenium Bridge, Millenium Bridge
```

### Bookings table (record for every booking including date and venue)

```
iso_date, venue,            event
01/01/01, All London,       1
02/01/01, London Tower,     2
02/01/01, Millenium Bridge, 3
04/01/01, London Bridge,    4
```

### Events table

```
event, status
1,     1
2,     0
3,     1
4,     1
```

Now I want to join the tables such that i get a record for every venue for every day regardless of whether it has been booked. Where a venue has a booking i only want to see it if the event status is 1.

### Output

```
iso_date, venue,            booked
01/01/01, All London,       1
01/01/01, London Tower,     1
01/01/01, London Bridge,    1
01/01/01, Millenium Bridge, 1
02/01/01, All London,       0
02/01/01, London Tower,     0
02/01/01, London Bridge,    0
02/01/01, Millenium Bridge, 1
03/01/01, All London,       0
03/01/01, London Tower,     0
03/01/01, London Bridge,    0
03/01/01, Millenium Bridge, 0
04/01/01, All London,       0
04/01/01, London Tower,     0
04/01/01, London Bridge,    1
04/01/01, Millenium Bridge, 0
```

I can't use the event status in the where clause as it will remove the record entirely.

I know I could use a subquery or some complex case statements, but is it possible i can intelligently join the tables to solve my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to write:

```
SELECT Calendar.iso_date AS iso_date,
       Venues.venue AS venue,
       COALESCE(Events.status, 0) AS booked
  FROM Calendar
 CROSS
  JOIN Venues
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN (      Bookings
         JOIN Events
           ON Events.event = Bookings.event
          AND Events.status = 1
       )
    ON Bookings.iso_date = Calendar.iso_date
   AND Bookings.venue = Venues.venue
;
```

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Comment: this is essentially what i'm currently doing. pretty simple when you just have one column "booked" but my actual query has a lot more- so i'm looking to avoid having to "condition" every column

Comment: @LeeTickett: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean. What does it mean to "condition" a column? What other kinds of columns do you expect to have?

Comment: well i've simplified my problem here. if you imagine i have more tables/columns to add in... i would have to add a CASE condition to every column to ensure it is only displayed if the event status = 1

Comment: @LeeTickett: To be honest, I'm not *sure* I understand what you need ("more tables/columns" is quite vague), but I've updated my answer with my best guess. The new version will give the same results as the old version; the difference is in its internals. `Bookings.XXX` will now be null for any `Bookings` record whose corresponding `Events.status` is non-`1`.

Comment: that's exactly it! i was struggling to get the syntax quite right... i had resorted to `left join (select * from blah join moo etc)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with a driving table, which is the cross join of calendar and venues.  Then, join in the bookings to get the booking information:

```
select c.iso_date, v.venue,
       (case when b.event is NULL then 0 else 1 end) as Booked
from calendar c cross join
     venues v left outer join
     bookings b
     on b.iso_date = c.iso_date and
        b.venue = v.venue
```

Comment: this is essentially what i'm currently doing. pretty simple when you just have one column "booked" but my actual query has a lot more- so i'm looking to avoid having to "condition" every column

Comment: @LeeTickett . . . This answers your question.  You should ask another question that does a better job of describing your situation.  Modifying the current question is unfair to the people who have answered it, possibly correctly.

Comment: i haven't edited my question and it quite clearly states: `I know I could use a subquery or some complex case statements, but is it possible i can intelligently join the tables to solve my problem?`

Answer (score 0):

```
select iso_date, 
       venue,
       max(case when events.event is not null then 1 else 0 end) as booked
    from calendar
    cross join venue
    left outer join bookings on
        bookings.date  = iso_date and
        bookings.venue = venue.venue
    left outer join events on 
        events.status = 1 and 
        events.event = bookings.event
    group by iso_date, venue
```

Update: rewrote the query with two outer joins so that it would be efficient even if only getting a small subset of the records.

Here is how you would most efficiently get a single date and venue:

```
select iso_date, 
       venue,
       max(case when events.event is not null then 1 else 0 end) as booked
    from calendar
    inner join venue on
        calendar.iso_date = '01/01/01' and
        venue.venue = 'my front lawn'
    left outer join bookings on
        bookings.date  = iso_date and
        bookings.venue = venue.venue
    left outer join events on 
        events.status = 1 and 
        events.event = bookings.event
    group by iso_date, venue
```

Comment: again, one of the possibilities i had considered but would like to avoid. do you know how the "subquery" is executed?

Comment: @LeeTickett, the subquery would be executed first and then joined to the outer query.  There is no particular reason to avoid that from a performance perspective.  In some specific cases it can be slower, but in this case your query is going to need to look at *all* bookings no matter how you design it, so it shouldn't hurt you. (well, unless your actual query is quite different from the sample one...)

Comment: but what about the date and venue filter(s)? i.e. if my query is only for one date i wouldn't want the subquery to be executed for all records before joining?

Comment: @LeeTickett, yes, but your question only mentioned obtaining *all* of the days and venues.  Getting a single record is a completely different question that requires a different design.

Comment: @LeeTickett, updated my answer to be efficient even on a subset.

Comment: i'm leaning more toward your original solution. it wont be all dates (that'd be 100's of years worth of data :) it will be a subset. i think despite it appearing a subquery, i think the execution plan suggests the optimiser is intelligent enough to evaluate only the necessary records. but essentially i think what we're saying is NO- it is not possible without using a subquery or case statements